# Android shape xml like below image

Tags: android, xml, shapes

[image: i need to create run in my xml]

I how can i create that shape in my xml (drawable folder).

Comment: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266384/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-asking-about-how-to-achieve-something-without-ha](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266384/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-asking-about-how-to-achieve-something-without-ha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawable_line.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/black"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/white
        android:endColor=  "@android:color/black"
        android:angle="360"
        />
</shape>
```

add it in your layout as `view`

```
<View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_line" />
```

Comment: yes that's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add These in activity_main :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and create drawable res file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="360"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/white"
        android:endColor="@android:color/black"
        android:startColor="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```